# error on booting desktop pc (asus MoBo)

Tags: bios

Each time i boot my desktop PC, the boot process stops and i am confronted with the following message
(My desktop MoBo is an asus M3N78 EM (AMD cpu and chipset)

**NEW CPU IS INSERTED IN YOUR SYSTEM !**

**PRESS F1 TO RUN SETUP**

**PRESS F2 TO LOAD DEFAULT VALUES AND CONTINUE**

I have done the following

- changed the cmos battery cell
- i have NOT changed the cpu ever
- pulled out the only hardware add-on (a PCIe card)
- reinstalled the bios

Hitting F2 will continue the boot process to my Windows 10 desktop

Would anyone have an idea why this is happening and what can be done ??

Comment: Checking if WHAT is correct?

Comment: Set what?  Save what? I do not have any new CPU as announced by the BIOS and no hardware changes either

Comment: Nothing has changed in my PC configuration or hardware,  BIOS has always been on default/  One fine day the mentioned error message pops up on boot so i asked what  could be done.  I found this ACUTELY annoying and in the bargain instead of some specific well worded advise i get read as OBFUSE. .Half help is as good as no help! and i thought no question in the world was STUPID (answers - YES for sure!

Comment: Of course I have indeed checked each element (that I could understand) so I expecting a more specific and less obfuscated answer for someone at this forum.

Comment: ....and if anyone thought I was trying to be punny in my reply and got BEFUDDLED with two words that belong to the world of GEOMETRY, well that would be 180 degrees away from reality.

Comment: You're still doing the 'shouting at people' thing. It's not going to help. You've been confrontational from the start. That's not the way to persuade people to help you. I'm out.

Comment: Must request people to read my first post and initial comment.  It was in the nature of a plea and not confrontational at all.   Later irritation at non-specific answers....and yes after someone pokes you, replying and standing up is not confrontational it is merely putting a view across.  Block letters is also used to emphasize and an entire paragraph in block letters may certainly be construed as SHOUTING.  Thanks for ALL the help though.